# WebDAV connections failing in 22.10

Tags: gvfs, nextcloud, webdav

I have been using the built-in backup tool (I think it's deja-dup-based) to perform system backups to a WebDAV point hosted on a public NextCloud instance for several years.  I noticed in the last week or so, that the backup tool spits out this message: [backup error message: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfZ29.png)

I did some digging in the log files and found this message in /var/log/syslog that correlates to connection attempts:

`Nov  1 12:42:14 [hostname-redacted] kernel: [ 4440.470840] gvfsd-dav[93326]: segfault at 0 ip 00007faba72323a7 sp 00007fffbb07dc88 error 4 in libc.so.6[7faba70c1000+179000]`

I can't clearly recall if I began seeing the behavior prior to last week's upgrade to 22.10 or not, but the last successful backup was 12 days ago (according to the tool), so it does appear that the behavior has begun since the upgrade.

I have also tried manually connecting to a WebDAV URL from Gnome Files with a similar error message: [Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mDQx.png)

At this point, I'm not sure what to do.  I tried installing gvfs2, thinking that perhaps WebDAV support hadn't been installed, but that didn't seem to change any behavior.

Update (November 3, 2022): I was able to successfully connect to the WebDAV URL on a 22.04 machine.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problem with 22.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1995743

On that page a simple fix is mentioned:

> For those having the same problem: You can simply replace the URL to
> open in order to make it work. Instead of
> /remote.php/dav/files/$USERNAME you can use /remote.php/webdav/

Works for me!

Comment: currently running a backup and confirmed that files are being written to the remote destination.  Thanks!